# Creating phpunit.xml file in phpunit

Tags: php, xml, phpunit

I have such structure of my project:

- Root
  -- /src
  -- /tests

In src are my file such a Task1.php. In tests folder are my tests files.
Example:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../src/Task1.php';
class Task1Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
 {
public function testTask1(){
    $this->assertEquals([1,1,1,3,5,9],fib([1,1,1],6));
}
}
```

I include my src files using `require __DIR__ . '/../src/Task1.php';`
I want to add **bootstrap.php** file  and include src files there. And then add bootstrap.php in phpunit.xml.

My phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" strict="true" bootstrap="bootstrap.php"></phpunit>
```

What should I write in bootstrap.php file?

I try add Autoloader.php file in tests folder:

```
<?php
class AutoLoader {

static private $classNames = array();

/**
 * Store the filename (sans extension) & full path of all ".php" files found
 */
public static function registerDirectory($dirName) {

    $di = new DirectoryIterator($dirName);
    foreach ($di as $file) {

        if ($file->isDir() && !$file->isLink() && !$file->isDot()) {
            // recurse into directories other than a few special ones
            self::registerDirectory($file->getPathname());
        } elseif (substr($file->getFilename(), -4) === '.php') {
            // save the class name / path of a .php file found
            $className = substr($file->getFilename(), 0, -4);
            AutoLoader::registerClass($className, $file->getPathname());
        }
    }
}

public static function registerClass($className, $fileName) {
    AutoLoader::$classNames[$className] = $fileName;
}

public static function loadClass($className) {
    if (isset(AutoLoader::$classNames[$className])) {
        require_once(AutoLoader::$classNames[$className]);
    }
  }

 }

spl_autoload_register(array('AutoLoader', 'loadClass'));
```

And bootsstrap.php in tests folder:

```
<?php
include_once('AutoLoader.php');
// Register the directory to your include files
AutoLoader::registerDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../src/');
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Do you use composer for autoloading purposes in your project?

Comment: No, I don't use it

Comment: Then it is a case of simply moving `require` from each test file to bootstrap.php file. Mind the paths. If you have many files and/or subdirectories it can be quite time consuming. Therefore next step I can suggest is to look into autoloading.

Comment: I edit my post, I tried to use autoloader, but it dosn't work. Can you help me, how can I write autoloading?

Comment: I would recommend to use composer for autoloading, not writing the autoloader yourself. It is fairly simple. Check article http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer the chapter "How to autoload the PSR-4 way?".

Comment: My files is such: `<?php
namespace Source;
/*
 *Calculation of the Fibonacci functions for 3 digits
 * [1 1 1]=>[1 1 1 3 5 9 ..]
 */
function fib($arr,$num){
    for($i=$num-3;$i>0;$i--){
        $arr[]=array_sum(array_slice($arr,-3));
    }
    return $arr;
}`

I added to composer.json:
 `"autoload":{
    "prs-4":{
      "Source\\":"src/"
    }
  }`

And ran : composer dumpautoload -o

What must I write my phpunit.xml now?

Answer (score 1):

I've carved two versions for you.

See https://github.com/Grawer/starckoverflow-41881997

First (branch global-functions) is a version with globally declared functions, the very basic one. What was done is basically the `require` is moved from file containing test to `bootstrap.php`, and that's all.

Second version (branch master), with autoloader is more complicated, and I realized that you might hold on with doing it. Still, I was insisting so here it is. You was almost there. There was a typo in your `composer.json` as you wrote `prs-4` and it is supposed to be `psr-4`. What was left was to add autoloader require to `bootstrap.php`, and you would also need to put `fib` function inside a class. Then you could access it, without needing to require that class in the test class file.

Comment: Thanks. I understood. But github project doesn't work for me. How I must run project? I use phpstprm configuration and run it with phpunit-4.8.32.phar

Comment: How do you define "doesn't work"?

All using command line.
For autoloader version:
- checkout branch `master`
- download composer.phar into project directory `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar`
- generate autoloader files `php composer.phar dump-autoload`
- run tests `phpunit`
I'm using PHPUnit 4.8.31.

For non-autoloader:
- checkout branch `global-functions`
- run tests `phpunit`

Answer (score 1):

if you are having problems with auto loader, and tests not working, try to do what I done, and change your `composer.json`

to include the lines:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "foo\\": "foo"
    }
  },
```

foo is the namespace. and the difference was I had psr-0 instead of psr-4.

Worked straight after!