# PHPUnit Error Class not found during test while trying to put separate folders of classes and tests

Tags: php, xml, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I have a similar question to the answer explained here:
[Creating phpunit.xml file in phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881997/creating-phpunit-xml-file-in-phpunit)

As I have my files in `root/src/foo`, and my tests in `root/tests/foo`.

Yet I just can't get them working separately. They working ok in the same folder.
But I can't seem to separate them.

I've tried the solution to that question, which shows a simple working example
https://github.com/Grawer/starckoverflow-41881997

Yet, that hasn't worked for me, even though I've used the same `bootstrap.php`, and `phpunit.xml`.

.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit
        bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
        colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite>
            <directory prefix="" suffix="Test.php">./tests/foo/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

bootstrap

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/../src/foo/ip_request.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I watched a youtube video and saw someone with the same error.

I only changed the following code inside `composer.json` and updated

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "foo\\": "foo"
    }
  },
```

psr-4 was at psr-0, and with that change, it fixed it.